# .isalpha() rompe mi función de Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo una duda con respecto al método .isalpha() de Python.
Tengo el código de esta función que cuenta cuantas veces aparece un carácter en un String.
Este es el código

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter not in result:
            result[letter] = 0
        result[letter] += 1
    return result

print(count_letters("AaBbCc"))
print(count_letters("Math is fun! 2+2=4"))
print(count_letters("This is a sentence."))
```

Aquí funciona correctamente y no hay mayor problema. Sin embargo al intentar validar que solamente cuente las coincidencias en letras usando el método *.isalpha()* de esta forma:

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter not in result and letter.isalpha():
            result[letter] = 0
        result[letter] += 1
    return result

print(count_letters("AaBbCc"))
print(count_letters("Math is fun! 2+2=4"))
print(count_letters("This is a sentence."))
```

la función me lanza el siguiente error en cualquiera de las últimas dos llamadas a la función:

> File "", line 10, in  File "", line 6, in
> count_letters KeyError: ' '

Les agradezco sus sugerencias / correcciones.

Answer (score 0):

La causa es simple: sólo creas entradas en el diccionario para las letras, pero luego intentas actualizar el diccionario con cualquier caracter que hayas leido. En particular, el error te da al procesar el caracter espacio en la segunda frase `"Math is fun! 2+2=4"`

#### Solución

Hay que reordenar los `if`, preguntando primero si es letra. En tal caso, puedo actualizar el diccionario. Si no, pasar a la siguiente iteración:

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter not in result:
                result[letter] = 0
            result[letter] += 1
    return result

print(count_letters("AaBbCc"))
print(count_letters("Math is fun! 2+2=4"))
print(count_letters("This is a sentence."))
```

produce:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
{'m': 1, 'a': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'f': 1, 'u': 1, 'n': 1}
{'t': 2, 'h': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 3, 'a': 1, 'e': 3, 'n': 2, 'c': 1}
```